# UIViewController: view needs to redisplay once data is fetched

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have `TransactionViewController` that looks like

```
@interface TransactionViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *yearHeaderLabel;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *monthHeaderLabel;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *transactionsCountHeaderLabel;
@end
```

In implementation, the code looks like

```
    @interface TransactionViewController ()
    @property(nonatomic, strong) TransactionsModel *transactionsModel;
    @end

    @implementation TransactionViewController


    - (id)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            [TransactionsAPI getTransactionsForYear:2014 AndMonth:9 completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *transactions) {
                self.transactionsModel = [[TransactionsModel alloc] initWithJson:transactions];
                NSLog(@"transactionsModelInViewController:%@", self.transactionsModel);
                [self viewWillAppear:YES];
            }];
        }
        return self;

    }
```

The data takes time to load from `API` server, the other methods don't wait since the call is asynchronous, they look like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.transactionsModel.transactions.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TransactionCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    TransactionCell *transactionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (transactionCell == nil) {
        transactionCell = [[TransactionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    TransactionModel *transactionModel = self.transactionsModel.transactions[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    [self setTransactionCell:transactionCell transactionModel:transactionModel];
        return transactionCell;
}
```

Now since `self.transactionsModel` was `nil` in first place, nothing is displayed, but eventually data is there, so I need to refresh the view. So I try

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But this doesn't work and my view is still blank. What can I do to fix this issue? what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource delegates if you are using a Basic UIViewControllers and UILabels

Comment: Do not ever call `viewWillAppear:` yourself. That will be done when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  a table view to display the data (Your code does not reflect that, see my comment), you can simply call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: something is wrong, because I do get compilation error on reloadData with self.tableView. I do not have it there

Comment: Do you have a table view inside your UIViewController in the Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, that code was just an example. You'd have to call that function on your wired instance of UITableView

Comment: Thanks, I have TableView on my ViewController, but not hooked up with anything, seems like I need to learn about it

Comment: Connect it to your header file the same way you wired up your labels. Don't forget to synthesize or access your UITableView like [_myTableView someFunction]; 

Also, you'll need to set the data source and delegate methods to point to your implementation like 

    [myTableView setDelegate: self];
    [myTableVie setDataSource: self];
That way your table view knows to look at your implementation file for the delegate functions.